# How to preload a template in my ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to preload a template in my div using ui-router.
This is my template.html file which is located in /templates folder.

```
// its location is templates/template1.html
<div>
    Template 1
</div>
```

The .config function in angularjs has the following code which includes the states. Here template1 is the child state of the state1

```
.state('state1',{
            url:'/state1',
            templateUrl:'templates/state1.html',
            controller: 'state1Controller',
        })
        .state('state1.template1',{
            templateUrl: 'templates/template1.html'
        })
```

Template1 is loaded when i press a button, but i want the template to be preloaded. What can i do to attain my desired result?

Answer (score 0):

**Declarative way**: Put all your template into a script tag with type as text/ng-template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId.html">
  <p>This is the content of the template</p>
</script>
```

**Code way**: Use $templateCache for this.

In state1Controller, **load your template and put it into cache** like this:

```
$templateCache.put('templateId.html', 'This is the content of the template');
```

Or load it with http:

```
$http.get('templates/template1.html').then(function(template){
   $templateCache.put('templateId.html', template);
})
```

**Then in your router definition**, put templateId.html as value of templateUrl

```
.state('state1.template1',{
    templateUrl: 'templateId.html'
})
```

and any time you request templateId.html, angular will automatically find template in $templateCache before sending request to server.